# In a bash shell script , how to write a loop that goes trough three values

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to write a shell script using bash for the following problem:

> Write a loop to go through three values (A B C) and displays each of these values to the screen (hint use a ‘for’ loop).

I figured out it would be something like this but I'm not sure, so any advice would be much appreciated.

```
For (( EXP1; EXP2; EXP3 ))
do
     command1
     command2
     command3
done
```

Comment: you want value exp1 to print or exp1 exp2 exp3 to execute ?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I want the value T exp 1 exp2 exp3 to execute

Comment: @cutzeroLonGdueZBOODacrovinungh, read the problem description again; it is unambiguously a duplicate.  The fact that the OP doesn't know the `echo` command doesn't change that.  *"...go through three values...display each of these values to the screen..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in Alpha Beta Charlie; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

You don't need `eval` and you don't need `ls`.

Alternatively, you could just print each of these directly, with a newline character after each:

```
printf '%s\n' Alpha Beta Charlie
```

Please don't use `eval` unless you *absolutely must*.  (Hint: Unless you get seriously complicated, you never need it.)  Using `eval` when you don't have to just leads to security holes.

---

Your initial question is very clear:

> Write a loop to go through three values (A B C) and displays each of these values to the screen (hint use a ‘for’ loop).

However from your comment perhaps you want to execute some commands in a loop:

> I want the value T exp 1 exp2 exp3 to execute

If you want to execute *commands* in a loop, just write the commands and put them in a loop:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
  echo Hip Hip
  echo 'HOORAY!'
done
```

The first line of this could just as easily be `for i in A B C; do` and it would do the same thing.  You don't use the variable `$i` anywhere in your loop, but you don't have to.  It will still execute three times.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @pfnuesel, I would say strategic downvotes by someone giving a very strange answer.  Your answer is perfectly fine; I started out the same but expanded it a little further.

Comment: no strategic, the exp must be executed.

Comment: omg i give up...

Comment: @cutzeroLonGdueZBOODacrovinungh, see edited answer.  Happy now?

Comment: no he wants exp to be executed, he cleary says "I want the value T exp 1 exp2 exp3 to execute "

Comment: @cutzeroLonGdueZBOODacrovinungh, well he accepted my answer.  If you have a different question perhaps you should ask it.  There's no such thing as "executing an expression"; only a command.  You could just say `expr1;expr2;expr3` to execute each of these *as a command* — but what on earth would it mean to "execute an expression"?  This isn't Lisp.

Comment: "eval takes its arguments, concatenates them separated by spaces, and executes the resulting string as Bash code" you can say what you want...

Comment: *sigh* @cutzero this is covered elsewhere.  **See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/5419599)**

Comment: i upvote since the edit

Answer (score 0):

That should be as simple as:

```
for i in A B C; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: no but he wants command to be executed